# How to get info box text with Python

Tags: python

Im sorry if this question sounds a bit vague, but I dont know the term for what I am looking for.

If you place your mouse cursor over an item in Windows and leave it there for a second, a box pops up with some text. For example, if you have your cursor on the 'e' icon,  a box will show up with the text "Microsoft Edge".

Is there a method, using Python, to read what that text is? So for the example given, I would like to write or call a function that returns a string containing "Microsoft Edge".

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: This website is not meant for people to write code for you, but rather to help you work your way through code you have already written. See this link for guidelines in posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: These popup boxes are generally called "tooltips".

Comment: Im not asking for anyone to write code for me, Im asking if anyone knows of a library or something that interfaces with these boxes

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to tooltips. It's possible to use python with BeautifulSoup to scrape these off the web.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Im not trying to do this with an HTML page, but knowing what they are called will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to get tooltip text from an icon displaying in the system tray. There are functions in class pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper(hwnd) in pywinauto module of python. For example GetTipText(tip_index)Return the text of the tooltip. You can try if these functions provide any help to you. But I was getting error like 'no windows found' when using control of the icon by classname as window handle. For e.g

```
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer")
    sys_tray = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
    hnd = sys_tray.childWindow(class_name= "ToolbarWindow32")``
    texts= pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper(hnd).texts()
    print(texts)
```

Documentation of pywinauto: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pywinauto-docs/docs-rework/pywinauto-docs.pdf

Comment: This is old docs for old pywinauto 0.5.4. Latest one is 0.6.5. Also direct usage of wrapper class is not recommended. See [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).